# How to make a bot send 2000+ characters in multiple embeds

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a lyrics command where the bot looks for the given song's title and provides the lyrics. But some songs have more than 2000 characters (like rap god). So I want to split my lyrics into two parts and send two embeds if the length of the lyrics is more that 2000 characters (like Rythm bot) and I don't know how to do this. Any help given will be appreciated. (discord.js version 12.3.1).
My code:

```
const { MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
const lyricsFinder = require('lyrics-finder')

module.exports = {
  name: "lyrics",
  category: "info",
  description: "Provides you the lyrics of the song",
  usage: `lyrics <song name>`,
  aliases: ['l'],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {

    if (!args[0]) {
      let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTitle(':x: Song title not provided!')
      return message.channel.send(embed)
    }
    let lyrics = await lyricsFinder(args.join(' ')) || "Not Found!";
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setDescription(lyrics)
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
}
```

But since some songs have more than 2000 characters, it gives me this error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.
    at RequestHandler.execute (E:\my bots\HimalBeta\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (E:\my bots\HimalBeta\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/763632986158923789/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like

```js
var str = 'abcdefghijkl';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,3}/g));
```

to split text. Change the 3 to 2000 and set `str` to your long string. Then just loop through them and send them all. (`str.match(/.{1,3}/g)` will return an array of strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach some options to a message, and `MessageOptions.split` is what you're searching for. When you want to send the text, do it like this:

```js
message.channel.send(lyrics, { split: true });
```

If `lyrics.length` is greater that the limit, discord.js will cut your messages and send them one after the other, making it seem like it's only one.

**EDIT**
For embed messages:

```
for(let i = 0; i < lyrics.length; i += 2000) {
    const toSend = lyrics.substring(i, Math.min(lyrics.length, i + 2000));
          const message_embed1 = new Embed.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle(`Lyrics`)
            .setDescription(toSend)
          message.channel.send(messaje_embed1)
}
```

Comment: This works for regular text, however OP specified they needed it for embed descriptions.

Comment: Worked on embed! Thanks it worked for my embed. I put "toSend" in the description value and it sends multiple embeds now thanks!

Answer (score -5):

You first have to send the first embed and then use .then() to send another embed afterwards.

Comment: I mean, how can I split my lyrics into two parts and send?